# How to use variable for file name in NSString in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsstring

Here is the sample code. How can I use this variable: "Readme.txt" as a file name?
Thanks in advance.

```
NSString *file_name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Readme"];
NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"%@",file_name  ofType:@"txt"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is ,

```
NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"%@",file_name  ofType:@"txt"];
```

Instead of that code as,

```
NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:file_name ofType:@"txt"];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply pass the variable in.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:file_name ofType:@"txt"];
```

Also, since you are defining `file_name` to be a constant string, you don't need to use the `stringWithFormat:` method. You can just define it directly.

```
NSString *file_name = @"Readme";
```

If the `file_name` variable is going to be Readme every time, then its a constant and doesn't need to be defined at all:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Readme" ofType:@"txt"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *file_name = @"Readme.txt";

NSString *name = [file_name stringByDeletingPathExtension];
NSString *extension = [file_name pathExtension];

NSString *file_path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:extension];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Readme"  ofType:@"txt"];
```